# Optimizing For Loops C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, optimization, vector

I have this small function that loops through a vector to find a given animal and return its habitat. I need to optimize it, but I'm hitting dead ends with what I could be doing. Three things that popped out at me was `size_t`, `i++`, and the fact I'm looping through a vector. I read that `size_t` is great for arrays that have a large size index. I know that `pre-increment` is better than `post-increment` since it changes the original value instead of creating a temp and incrementing. But compilers usually optimize this small difference anyway. Finally, the last thing I thought was that this vector could be unsorted, therefore dipping in performance. I was thinking of sorting the vector by the species variable of animals, then maybe porting it into a `BST` to search since the time complexity would be `O(log(n))`. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
string GetAnimalHabitat(vector<Animal> animals, string species)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++)
    {
        if (animals[i].species == species)

        {
            return animals[i].habitat;
        }
    }
    return "Animal not within records.";
}
```

Is there anything that I'm potentially missing that could improve this function? Any tips would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use a `vector`, use a `map` or `unordered_map`. Then you wouldn't need a loop at all. Micro-optimizing the loop is unlikely to give you noticeably better performance than you're getting already.

Comment: Considering things like `size_t` and pre-vs-post increment are not worth your time. You need to consider a different data structure. Have you considered a [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)?

Comment: Is this data sorted?

Comment: Ah yes! A map. That totally glossed over my mind. That would make WAY more sense.

Comment: @Jake Freeman it is unknown if this vector is sorted or not.

Comment: One more thing, but not pertaining to your loop. You pass your `species` string into the function by value. Normally this would be fine as species are generally short strings using short string optimizations. However it is good practice to use `std::string&` or `const std::string&` to pass in your `species` string.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo A bigger issue along those lines, which might well be the biggest cost in the function, is that the vector is also passed by value.

Answer (score 6):

A `std::map` surely works better than looping over a vector here:

```
string GetAnimalHabitat(const map<string, string>& animals, const string& species)
{
    auto search = animals.find(species);
    if (search != animals.end())
        return search->second;
    return string("Animal not within records.");
}
```

It requires building a map first, however. But building it once is enough and you only have to add new key pairs to it:

```
map<string, string> build_map(const vector<Animal>& animals)
{
    map<string, string> ret;
    for (const auto& x : animals)
        ret[x.species] = x.habitat;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Why not pass inputs by reference?

Comment: @PhotometricStereo Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is reduce the number of times .size() method gets called, by doing something like this:

```
size_t vectorSize = animals.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++)
{
    if (animals[i].species == species)

    {
        return animals[i].habitat;
    }
}
```

Another minor one would be to change `i++` to `++i`. The purpose of this is to avoid storing the value of `i` in a register every time it increments.

Comment: I highly doubt that any modern compiler will not optimise `i++` to `++i` when `i` is an `int` and the incrementation is the only operation between the `;`s

Comment: Better than both of these is to switch to a range-based for loop.

Comment: @DanielH a range-based for loop might look a little cleaner, but I doubt the compiler will generate more efficient code for it.

Comment: @MarkRansom It won't do things like call `size()` multiple times or increment iterators in a slow way, which is all that this answer talks about. I agree those are relatively small changes and that switching to range-based for loops won't be a big improvement, but when there's a difference I expect them to be slightly better than a non-range-based option.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, you want to stop making a full copy of the vector and all its elements each time you call this function.  If you're needing to optimize, I assume the vector is large, so why not pass a reference to a const vector?

Second, another problem is how many elements of the vector will match your input string?  If it's just a few, then scanning the whole vector is loading a lot of memory just to look at it to decide you don't need it.  Since you return after the first match, it's reasonable to think there is at most one of each species, and in that case an associative container is better.

Some latency sensitive places partition data into different groups so no "filtering" is necessary.  Just look at the group of things you care about and only process those.

Another thing to consider, a string comparison is much slower than something like an integer comparison.  You could pre-hash the species into the class, hash the species parameter before your loop, and compare the hashes.  If they are equal, THEN compare the strings to make sure it's a real match.

But my guess is most of your time is spent copying your inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unordered_map` makes the most sense since order is not important

```
string GetAnimalHabitat(const std::unordered_map<string, string>& animals, const string& species)
{
    auto search = animals.find(species);
    if (search != animals.end())
        return search->second;
    return string("Animal not within records.");
}
```

It requires building a map first, however. But building it once is enough and you only have to add new key pairs to it.   Note that first time you pass a empty unordered_map in, after that you pass a vector of new values and the current map:

```
build_map(const std::vector<Animal>& animals, std::unordered_map<string_string> * ret)
{
    for (const auto& x : animals)
        ret[x.species] = x.habitat;
}
```